# How to print out native stacktrace in Java?

Tags: java, native

I would like to print the `stacktrace` of native methods calls of a Java application. The `Thread.dumpStack()` is only printing java methods calls.

Comment: Just to clarify, by native do you mean the native keyword or the C level function calls within the JVM?

Comment: C level function calls within the jvm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the non-java stack, you need a "native" debugger, e.g. `gdb`.

You can attach to your running java with `gdb`, too.

For documentation on *seamless* debugging of Java with gdb, see also: http://gcc.gnu.org/java/gdb.html

(gcc can compile java code to native code; at which point the native debugger will also show Java backtraces.)

Comment: I need a symbol table right ? I cannot run gdb without it

Comment: You should of course do a *debug build* of your native library, and if you want to see details on hotspot, install the debug symbols of your JRE, too. (e.g. Ubuntu package `openjdk-8-dbg`)

Comment: `javac TestT.java gcj -g --main=TestT -o TestT TestT.class gdb TestT` I Should I install gcj : the Gnu Compiler for Java as well ?

Comment: If you want to do the seamless debugging approach, then yes. If you want to use OpenJDK/HotSpot, no.

Comment: so I just do `gdb --args java TestT`

Comment: Or `gdb java PID` to attach to a running java process with process id `PID`.

Answer (score 2):

If it is OK to do it outside of your application you can run `$JAVA_HOME/bin/jstack -m <jvm_pid>`

Comment: But what if I want the native method calls for a class `HelloWorld.java` ?

Comment: I get this output when I run gdb (no debugging symbols found)

Answer (score 2):

To view the internal JVM (C-level) function calls, attach a standard C debugger to the process.

Exactly how to do this does depends on your OS and debugger of choice, for example on OSX one would use xcode.  Instructions for using gdb can be read [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/01/debugging-jvm.html).